# File Not found error in tmp folder when installing the framework as prerequisite in inno setup

Tags: .net, installation, frameworks, inno-setup

I am installing the dotnet framework 3.5 as prerequisite and below is my code. 
When I run this code, I get below error. Can some one let me know why the "tmp" folder is not recognizing the file.
**EDIT**
I have used "AfterInstall" instead of "BeforeInstall" as mentioned in this sample code and it worked fine.

[image: Error]

When I evaluate the constant I found the path as below.

[image: Path]

```
[Files]
Source: "dotnetfx35setup.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: deleteafterinstall; BeforeInstall: Install35Framework; Check: Framework35IsNotInstalled

[Code]
function Framework35IsNotInstalled: Boolean;
begin
 if IsDotNetDetected( 'v3.5'  , 1) then
   begin
      Result := False;
   end else begin
     Result := True;
   end;
end;

procedure Install35Framework;
var
  StatusText: string;
    ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing .NET framework 3.5...';
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  try
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotnetfx35setup.exe'), '/q /norestart', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
      begin
          { you can interact with the user that the installation failed }
          MsgBox('.NET framework 3.5 installation failed with code: ' + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode) + '.',mbError, MB_OK);
        end;
  finally
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the installer *before* installing it:

```pascal
BeforeInstall: Install35Framework
```

Use `AfterInstall` instead.

Comment: Did my answer help you?